# How to set up a RTC clock in Ubuntu Core?

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, rtc

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 that register data in time, so I need an RTC clock

I've attached `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231` to config.txt.

`hwclock.service` would be perfect, but it is masked, and I can't unmask it.

`hwclock -s` works fine, but when I try to execute from a confined snap I get this (time-control is connected):

```
ed10vi86@localhost:~$ sudo hwclock.hwclock-test -s --debug
hwclock from util-linux 2.27.1
Using the /dev interface to the clock.
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
/dev/rtc does not have interrupt functions. Waiting in loop for time from /dev/rtc to change
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2017/06/29 10:49:54
Hw clock time : 2017/06/29 10:49:54 = 1498733394 seconds since 1969
Time since last adjustment is 1498733394 seconds
Calculated Hardware Clock drift is 0.000000 seconds
Calling settimeofday:
    tv.tv_sec = 1498733394, tv.tv_usec = 0
    tz.tz_minuteswest = -120
/snap/hwclock/x1/hwclock-test: line 2:  1656 Bad system call         hwclock $@
```

And snappy-debug.security scanlog:

```
= Seccomp =
Time: Jun 29 12:49:54
Log: auid=1000 uid=0 gid=0 ses=1 pid=1656 comm="hwclock" exe="/sbin/hwclock" sig=31 arch=40000028 79(settimeofday) compat=0 ip=0x76f0c246 code=0x0
Syscall: settimeofday
```

Works fine in devmode

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of a delayed response, but I figured I'd share my solution. It seems that you can "recreate" the `hwclock` service and get the desired result, as follows:

In order to unmask a service, the corresponding definition file needs to be present in `/etc/systemd/system`. Luckily, in Ubuntu Core this directory is mapped to `/writable/system-data/etc/systemd/system` - so in that writable directory you can create a file called `hwclock.service` with the following contents (tweaked if desired):

```
[Unit]
Description=Hardware clock synchronization
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/hwclock --hctosys --utc --adjfile=/writable/system-data/etc/adjtime
ExecStop=/sbin/hwclock --systohc --utc --adjfile=/writable/system-data/etc/adjtime
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you can unmask and enable the service as normal:

```
sudo systemctl unmask hwclock
sudo systemctl enable hwclock
```